# $\mathcal V(y^2-x^2(x-\lambda))$ is rational

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to show, that $$C_\lambda = \mathcal V(y^2-x^2(x-\lambda))$$ is rational. Where $\lambda$ is in a field $K$ and $\lambda \ne 0$. I am given that a parametrization of $C_\lambda$ is the inverse of $$\phi: C_\lambda \dashrightarrow \mathbb A^1, (x,y)\mapsto \frac x y.$$
So there must be $p(t),q(t),u(t),v(t)\in K[t]$, such that $$\phi^{-1}: \mathbb A^1 \dashrightarrow \mathbb A^2, t \mapsto \left(\frac{p(t)}{q(t)}, \frac{u(t)}{v(t)}\right).$$
There are $(\pm\lambda, 0), (0,0)\in C_\lambda$ for certain. But $\phi$ is not defined for any of these points. How can I find $\phi^{-1}$? Is there any geometric interpretation like in the case of stereographic projection?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't rational mean "birational to $\mathbb{P}^1$" (or equivalently, $\mathbb{A}^1$? So it doesn't matter that $\phi$ isn't defined at a finite number of points (namely the intersection with $y=0$). Also $(-\lambda,0)$ is not on the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually arrange for the parameterization of $C_\lambda$ to be given by polynomials, i.e. there's a regular map $\psi:\Bbb A^1\to C_\lambda$ which is an isomorphism except at finitely many points. (In particular, you can get an isomorphism away from the singular point $(0,0)$.)

Bezout's theorem and some basic intersection theory provides a geometric explanation of why this works. Any line in the projective plane intersects the projectivization of $C_\lambda$ with multiplicity 3, and the intersection multiplicity at $(0,0)$ is at least two. So the third point of intersection of a line through $(0,0)$ with $C_\lambda$ is uniquely determined by the slope of the line through $(0,0)$, and it remains to check that this gives us a rational parameterization.

Let $t$ be the slope of a line $\ell = V(y=tx)$ through $(0,0)$. Substituting this equation in to the equation of $C_\lambda$ to eliminate $y$, we get $t^2x^2=x^2(x-\lambda)$, or $x^3-(\lambda+t^2)x^2=0$. The sum of the roots of this equation is $\lambda+t^2$, and since $x=0$ is two of those roots, we find that the third root is $x=\lambda+t^2$. So $(\lambda+t^2,\lambda t+t^3)$ is the third point on the curve, meaning we have a parameterization  $\Bbb A^1\to C_\lambda$ given by $$t\mapsto (\lambda+t^2,\lambda t+t^3),$$ and this is a rational inverse to the rational map $C_\lambda \dashrightarrow \Bbb A^1$ given by sending $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{y}{x}$.

If you want to see this process on a graph, [click here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kjiuaji2zo) to play around with it!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!